# loader.properties are not read in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

My `loader.properties` file contains only one entry:

```
   loader.path=BOOT-INF/classes/config/common,BOOT-INF/classes/config/wres-ws,BOOT-INF/lib
```

It's added correctly to jar, but when I run it it's found but not read. I get:

```
$ java -Dloader.debug=true -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Trying file: C:\dev\myapp/loader.properties
Not found: file:C:\dev\myapp/loader.properties
Trying classpath: /loader.properties
Not found: classpath:loader.properties
Trying classpath: /BOOT-INF/classes/loader.properties
Found: classpath:BOOT-INF/classes/loader.properties
Property 'loader.path' from environment:
Nested archive paths: [/]
Adding classpath entries from nested /
```

But when I run:

```
$ java -Dloader.debug=true -Dloader.path=BOOT-INF/classes/config/common,BOOT-INF/classes/config/wres-ws,BOOT-INF/lib -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Trying file: C:\dev\myapp/loader.properties
Not found: file:C:\dev\myapp/loader.properties
Trying classpath: /loader.properties
Not found: classpath:loader.properties
Trying classpath: /BOOT-INF/classes/loader.properties
Found: classpath:BOOT-INF/classes/loader.properties
Property 'loader.path' from environment: BOOT-INF/classes/config/common,BOOT-INF/classes/config/wres-ws,BOOT-INF/lib
Nested archive paths: [BOOT-INF/classes/config/common/, BOOT-INF/classes/config/wres-ws/, BOOT-INF/lib/]
Adding classpath entries from nested BOOT-INF/classes/config/common/
Adding classpath entries from nested BOOT-INF/classes/config/wres-ws/
Adding classpath entries from nested BOOT-INF/lib/
```

property is read from environment and all paths added to classpath.

How do I fix it?

Comment: It looks as if `loader.path` is coming from the environment when you don’t specify it as a system property. What environment variables do you have set? In addition to `loader.path`, things like `loader_path` and `LOADER_PATH` will also match.

Comment: According to docs it should read loader.properties file when it's found as in this case. This should be sufficient. I don't want to specify loader.path in any other way.

Comment: Properties in loader.properties have lower precedence than those provided as system properties and environment variables. I believe you have an environment variable set and it is preventing the property in loader.properties from being used.

Comment: I don't have any environment properties set that could impact this. I believe if I had the log file would have shown it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your pom.xml you have "ZIP" layout set for spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Reference document [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout> <!-- to support PropertiesLaunchar -->
            </configuration>
            ...
        </plugin>
```